# django HttpRequest.GET

Tags: python, django, get, httprequest

I want to send a GET request to another url from my python script...
the django docs say `HttpRequestGET` can do this, but i don't understand how do i form the URL with the variables and their values..

some example code:

```
data = {'name': 'qqq', 'age':'13',}
url='http://example.com/'
#expected result: http://example.com/?name=qqq&age=13
```

the docs say that `HttpRequestGET` is simply a `QueryDict` but its really not clear as how to form the URL..

Comment: I think you're mixing plain python with django. Although you can use some django features in a plain python, most of the features only makes sense if you're in a django application. What is exactly you're trying to achieve with this?

Comment: The Django docs say no such thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HttpRequest` object in Django represents HTTP request your Django application received. `HttpResponse.GET` is a read-only object that contains GET params of request.

If you want to issue a GET request look at [requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

Comment: `import requests`
`payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}`
`r = requests.get("http://httpbin.org/get", params=payload)`